MariaDB self join with ORDER BY and LIMIT
I'm having problems writing an SQL query to run on the following system:

Operating system: Debian 11 (bullseye)
Database: MariaDB 10.5.15 (the version packaged for bullseye)

The table schema (with some sample data):
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reference_log;

CREATE TABLE reference_log
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  reference_number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  reference_date DATE NOT NULL,
  log_date DATE NOT NULL
) Engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO reference_log (
    id,
    reference_number,
    reference_date,
    log_date
) VALUES (
    1, 
    '123',
    '2024-04-01',
    '2024-04-14'
);

INSERT INTO reference_log (
    id,
    reference_number,
    reference_date,
    log_date
) VALUES (
    2, 
    '123',
    '2024-04-01',
    '2024-04-15'
);

INSERT INTO reference_log (
    id,
    reference_number,
    reference_date,
    log_date
) VALUES (
    3, 
    '123',
    '2024-04-01',
    '2024-05-01'
);

INSERT INTO reference_log (
    id,
    reference_number,
    reference_date,
    log_date
) VALUES (
    4, 
    '123',
    '2024-05-01',
    '2024-05-06'
);

The rows have the following attributes, which are enforced by the application but not the database (i.e. there are no CONSTRAINTs):

An earlier id will always have the same or earlier log_date (rows are inserted in ascending order of log_date).
The tuple (reference_number, log_date) is always unique.
The tuple (reference_number, reference_date) is not unique and there will be a lot of duplicates, however these rows will always be inserted in ascending order of reference_date.
There may be gaps in log_date for a given reference_number. For example, a reference number may have rows for log dates of 2024-01-01, 2024-01-02, 2024-01-05.
reference_date will always be less than or equal to log_date.

Other relevant stats:

Any given log_date will have approximately 7,000 rows.
There are over 2 million rows in total.

I'm looking to find all reference numbers for a given log date where the previous instance has an earlier reference date. The previous instance is defined as the row with the same reference number and a lower id. If there's more than one (which is often the case), the one with the highest id is used. Any combination is possible for the previous instance, i.e.

No previous instance.
Previous instance has the same reference date.
Previous instance has a different reference date (this will always be an earlier date due to the attributes listed above).

Using the sample data, I would expect the following:

No rows returned for a log_date of 2024-05-01 (previous instance has the same reference_date)
1 row returned for a log date of 2024-05-06 (previous instance has an earlier reference_date)

I can get all the reference numbers for a log date easily:
SELECT reference_number
FROM reference_log
WHERE
  log_date = '2024-05-01'

I can also get the previous instance for a specific reference number ('123') and ID (50):
SELECT reference_number
FROM reference_log
WHERE
  reference_number = '123'
  AND id < 50
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1

What I'm struggling with is how to combine the two queries. If I didn't need the ORDER BY and LIMIT then a self-join would be straightforward, albeit very slow (takes over 4 minutes to execute due to 'range checked for each record' and there are over 2 million rows):
SELECT
  rl1.reference_number
FROM reference_log rl1, reference_log rl2
WHERE
  rl1.log_date = '2024-05-01'
  AND rl2.reference_number = rl1.reference_number
  AND rl2.id < rl1.id
  AND rl2.reference_date < rl1.reference_date

Is there a way to get what I need using a single query?
The only other option would be to fetch each row for a given log_date and then issue another query to find the previous instance. However, there are usually around 7,000 reference numbers for each log_date so that would mean issuing 7,000 queries. It also means I can't test the query directly against the database (I prefer to do this where possible as I can be sure that any errors aren't a result of bugs in the application).

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

what's the approximate average number of rows for each reference number? or put another way, how many distinct reference numbers are there?

output of show create table reference_log please?

@ysth Those are two different questions. Each reference number has around 300-400 rows. There are roughly 7,000 distinct reference numbers (hence over 2 million rows in total: 300-400 x 7000). The CREATE TABLE output is already in the question.

your create table statement does not give all the information that show create table does

so using LAG is probably your best bet, but since it will need to read the entire table it isn't going to be super fast.   an index on reference_number may or may not help it

You can try simpler approach - use window function
select *
from(
  select *
    ,coalesce(lag(reference_date)
                 over(partition by reference_number order by id)
       ,reference_date)prev_ref_date
  from reference_log
  where log_date<=cast('2024-05-06' as date)
)logprev
where reference_date<>prev_ref_date

Output is



id
reference_number
reference_date
log_date
prev_ref_date




4
123
2024-05-01
2024-05-06
2024-04-01



With index on(reference_number,id) the performance should be satisfactory.
In any case, it's better than self or cartesian join.
demo
If index not used, I would try to reverse the order in the window function
lag(reference_date)
      over(partition by reference_number 
          order by log_date desc, id esc)

and create an index(reference_number,log_date desc,id desc).

Thanks, this seems to work but I need to spot-check a few records to make sure it's definitely what I want. It takes 20s to run and the suggested index doesn't seem to help (it's not being used according to the output of EXPLAIN, and the query takes about the same amount of time - swapping the index to (id, reference_number) also doesn't make a difference).

question says "I'm looking to find all reference numbers for a given log date where the previous instance has an earlier reference date."  you are missing the specific log date part; but that's just adding to the outer WHERE; the subquery still needs to do all the records

Yes, some additional restrictions can (should) be added to the selection of a part of the rows. I think this is just the current formulation of the task, for example, with the daily execution of this operation. It would be clearer if it were further explained why exactly by one date. And what is will do with the founded rows.

I had added the outer WHERE clause (log_date = X) but it is still taking 20 seconds. The purpose is to work out which reference numbers have had their reference date changed on a given log date (they are logged every day, even if they have not changed).

Accepting this as the answer as I've manually checked the results for a couple of log dates (there are usually about 5-10 that match, out of 7,000) and all the ones I expect are included and none of the others. It's still very slow but I will try changing the indexes and see if there is anything else I can do to speed it up (it's a template that will be used for other similar queries and about 10 will run each time, so it needs to be a couple of seconds at most).
